# Angular module per page vs component per page?

Tags: angular, module, components

We are starting off Angular 8 and would like to make a web application that looks like this:

1. Navigation bar on the top with several drop down menu items,
   each pointing to a different UI page.
2. The middle section is for displaying "each page". 
   Example: 1. Sales section
           2. Customer list section
           3. Account Receivables section
3. Bottom is footer

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
NAVIGATION MENU         Sales     CustomerList       AcctReceivable 
-----------------------------------------------------------------


DIFFERENT PAGES / SECTIONS
(Sales page/CustomerList/AcctReceivable)





------------------------------------------------------------------
FOOTER
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The nav bar and footer remains static across the application. However the middle section changes depending on what menu item the user clicks and the hyper link it embeds.

What is the angular 8 way of organizing this app?

1. Should it be one module application, with each menu item (page) [lazy] loading respective component in middle section?
2. Should there be multiple modules for each page, with Navigation and Footer being common imported components and being displayed at top and bottom in each module?

Answer (score 4):

In your case 1. Sales section 2. Customer list section 3. Account Receivables section are features. So you should create a feature module for each one of these 
Navigation bar and footer content are not changing and should be loaded in the beginning itself, so they should be in core modules

For further reference you can refer to 
 1. For structuring  https://medium.com/@sdbala/structuring-angular-applications-ee9ed3910e9c 
 2. For routing https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-router-nested-routes-and-nested-auxiliary-routes-build-a-menu-navigation-system/

You can only lazy load modules and not separate components. So its better to use feature modules and in that case you can split your features into multiple components if needed. 
For example if Sales section has a detail part and a table. These can be 2 components and if table is the one which can be generalised and used in different modules then you can add table component to shared module